# Parallel processing of List in java

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a list of objects with list size of 500K. 
Each object in the list have a unique identifier. 
I want to validate the list for any duplicate objects(having the same identifier) and mark them with a flag.
Since there are lot of elements in the list, the processing takes quite long time and i am not able to achieve within allotted time frame.

Is there any way to process the list in parallel(Using java Future/Callable)?

Thanks in advance.
Mayuran

Comment: If *identifier* is the only criteria for 2 objects being equal, then why don't you override `equals()` and `hashCode()` and use a `Set` ?

Comment: Take a look at Java8 parallel streams.

Comment: Divide the chunk into smaller pieces and process it

Comment: How do you process the list right now? Post relevant code!

Comment: List is already prepared and i need to get the duplicate objects as well. If two objects is having same identifier, the first one is accepted and the second one is the rejected one.

Comment: @subhrajyoti Majumder, If i divide the list, how can i check for duplicate? The duplicate object may be in the another divided list

Comment: @isnot2bad, Currently i iterate through the list and validate one by one

Comment: like map-reduce in java 8 you will get this with parallel streaming

Comment: Searching for duplicates in a list is more than just iterating the list one by one. Again: Post your code!

Comment: put all objects in an array and sort them (using special Comparator or make objects to implement Comparable). Then scan the array and find duplicates. Only then decide if you need parallel processing.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what your definition of a long time is, but 500K object is not a lot. Most likely your algorithm is quite inefficient. Rather than relying on parallelisation (how would you parallelise this anyway?), consider using a better data structure/algorithm for this.

`HashMap` or `HashSet` should work quite well for this.

Comment: Thanks, but each object has to go through lot of validation scenarios. So validation for each object takes some time. So that i want to process in parallel

Comment: @Mayuran: That's not what your questions says. You might want to work on improving the clarity of the question then.